# Wrap each newline (/n) with <li> </li>

Tags: razor, razor-2

I have a small project which i have a question for. Users fill out a form and after submitting it i wish to wrap each new line in the textarea with `<li></li>`.

So basically i have the following code.

```
<textarea name="Questions"></textarea>
```

On the other submit.cshtml i wish to wrap each newline with `<li></li>` before the email is sent out. So the email will contain the following

- Question 1
- Question 2
- Question 3
- Question 4

the information in the textarea gets stored in a variable called `Questions`
I wish to break that variables each new line into `<li></li>` and store the new value in a second variable called `EmailBody` to be included in an email.

I know how to do this i PhP but in Razor view engine i'm kind of at a loss.
Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**
Solved it by modifying Aron's code to this.

```
    foreach (var line in Questions.Split('\n'))
    {
        EmailBody = EmailBody + "<li>" + @line + "</li>";
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean? What do you mean `EmailBody` to be included in an email? It seems like you are using Razor in a non-standard way (you aren't writing a MVC View). I think you need to expand with a [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Correct, i'm not using MVC view for this project. Mainly because the site does only contain a couple of .cshtml pages. One where you can send questions.
Questions.cshtml
The page has form containing <textarea name="Questions"></textarea>
submit.cshtml
has a variable looking like this
var Questions = Request["Questions"];
The Question variable i wish to split each new line into <li> and store the new values in a variable called EmailBody which will be included in the Email Helper when sending the email. 

Im only looking for the Split Questions /n and store the <li></li> in a EmailBody.

Comment: You aren't making any sense at all. What do you mean store in a EmailBody. You aren't making sense. Razor is a ViewEngine. Do you want to write in line C#? If so...please don't. Razor is a ViewEngine. You are taking about logic, it might work... But so would be like installing a petrol generator inside you TV. And just as likely to electrocute you...

Comment: Solved it by modifying your code to the purpose. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@foreach(var line in Model.Text.Split(Environment.NewLine)){
    <li>@line</li>
}
```

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work, searched for references on the Model.Text.Split but have found no reference to read about it? This is the code i have now.
`  foreach (var line in Model.Text.Split(Environment.NewLine))
            {
                EmailBody = EmailBody + "<li>" + @line + "</li>";
            }  `
I wish to split the variable Questions into `<li>` on each new line, add them to a variable that will be part of an email Body for an email that's gets sent out.

Comment: I have no idea where you are storing the `Text` variable, so I assumed you had a `Model`, with a property `Text`. How on earth am I meant to divine your class structure if you don't post. I assumed you would take my code and figure out what it means, and adapt it for your own needs...

Comment: I'm sorry if my explanation was weak, i updated my main questions with more information regarding the thing i'm looking for.